# My flutter permission handler notification permission permanently denied

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

I use 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart to ask permissions, when i ask notification permission, my permission initially denied, other permissions work normally.
Here is my code:

```
 Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await Permission.notification.request();
    await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.microphone.request();
```

camera and microphone permission work.

Comment: Did you deny the permission yourself before? If you deny a permission on Android twice it won't ask it again and automatically denies then. You can grant the permission in the app settings then. Or after a clean reinstall of the app

Comment: I didn't deny permission, I wipe data from my emulator to test permission, and it is permanently denied

Comment: I'm not sure, but could be that emulators never can grant that permission because notifications don't work on them maybe. Try on a real device. I could be wrong